# Defining bash function dynamically using eval

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I'm trying to define a bash function dynamically using following code:

```
delegate_function() { echo "output from delegate"; }
eval "parent_function() { echo $(delegate_function); }"
```

The intent is to have parent function dynamically dispatch to the delegate when executed. However due to the way `eval` works my function is being defined as follows:

```
kshitiz:/tmp$ type parent_function
parent_function is a function
parent_function () 
{ 
    echo output from delegate
}
```

How can I instead have the definition as:

```
 parent_function () 
 { 
     echo $(delegate_function);
 }
```

Is there a way to escape some part of the string from being evaluated by `eval`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escaping `$` should be enough to make this work:

```
eval "parent_function() { echo \$(delegate_function); }"
```

Answer (score 12):

In bash, like in most languages, `eval` is something to avoid.  See, for example, Greg's FAQ: [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

You can define `parent_function` like this:

```
parent_function=delegate_function
```

Anytime that you want to use `parent_function` to dispatch `delegate_function`, just run:

```
$ $parent_function
output from delegate
```

#### Example of dynamic function update

Let's define `delegate_function` and `parent_function` and run `$parent_function`:

```
$ delegate_function() { echo "delegate version 1"; }
$ parent_function=delegate_function
$ $parent_function
delegate version 1
```

Now let's change `delegate_function` and run `$parent_function` again:

```
$ delegate_function() { echo "delegate version 2"; }
$ $parent_function
delegate version 2
```

`$parent_function` instantly updates to run the new version of delegate_function.

#### Example of dynamic choice of name

Let's create our delegate function:

```
$ delegate_function() { echo "delegate function executed"; }
```

Let's assign some name:

```
$ parent_function=some_name
```

Now, let's demonstrate dynamic assignment of that name:

```
$ typeset $parent_function=delegate_function
$ $some_name
delegate function executed
```

Comment: That link should be trumpeted far and wide; thanks for providing it.

Comment: Though I appreciate the warning about pitfalls of eval, this does not satisfy my requirements as it hard codes the parent function name, while I need it to be dynamic. adonis' answer provides the right solution.

Comment: @John1024 Sorry what I meant is that `parent_function` is hardcoded in code. Its name should come from contents of a variable. Sometimes grandpa_function other times xt738_function.

Comment: Background: I want to automatically define shell based wrappers for my golang functions. My shell script will scan a directory for golang files, read the function names and then define bash functions with same names that internally invoke the golang functions. There's no security risk here as I'm not evaluating user input, just defining a convenient means to access my own golang functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `parent_function` to produce the output from `delegate_function`, along with some other stuff, e.g.,

```
parent_function()
{
    other command(s)
    echo $(delegate_function)
    other command(s)
}
```

then, if the output from `delegate_function` is just a single line, you can simplify the above to

```
parent_function()
{
    other command(s)
    delegate_function
    other command(s)
}
```

P.S. You don't need to use `;` at the end of a line;
use it (as a separator)
only when you're putting multiple things on the same line.